# Transform the database results to match the Account schema specified in the accounts-api.raml file

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

I'm trying to use dataweave visual mapper to map name(return from db) to firstname and last name for that I need to split the string(name), I'm using splitBy() function of dataweave 
splitBy(String, String): Array as you can see it returns array of string and I want to have just hello against the firstname key
sample input: firstName: "hello world" splitBy(" ")
sample output: firstname: [ "hello", "world" ],

mycode:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

---
payload map ( payload01 , indexOfPayload01 ) -> {
    id: payload01.accountID default "",
    firstName: "payload01.name" splitBy(" "), 
    address: ((payload01.street default "") ++ (payload01.city default "")) ++ (payload01.state default ""),
    postal: payload01.postal default "",
    country: payload01.country default "",
    creationDate: payload01.creationDate as String default "",
    accountType: payload01.accountType default "",
    miles: payload01.miles default 0
}
```

update:
I achieved this in dataweave by my making a userdefine function that calls splitBy() function In the code below I'm parsing the name return from db in firstname and last name

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
fun split(data) = data splitBy (" ")
---
payload map ( payload01 , indexOfPayload01 ) -> {
    id: payload01.accountID default "",
    address: ((payload01.street default "") ++ (payload01.city default "")) ++ (payload01.state default ""),
    postal: payload01.postal default "",
    country: payload01.country default "",
    creationDate: payload01.creationDate as String default "",
    accountType: payload01.accountType default "",
    firstName: split(payload01.name)[0],
    lastName: split(payload01.name)[1],
    miles: payload01.miles default 0
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you just need to select the first item in the resulting array:

`firstName : (payload01.name splitBy " ")[0]`

Comment: this solution not working for me, yes I can access it with index but other thing is splitBy is a function expecting string as argument when I'm passing payload1.name like this it's throwing error expecting string but got null in order to remove this if I passes "payload1.name" like this it's taking it literally, I want to have it's value parsed in firstname n lastname